# Solaris11: can be installed as zone on omnios or similar?

Tags: solaris, omnios

I can install Solaris11 as qemu vm on Omnios,my question is: is possible (maybe using an archiveadm "flash" archive) to install Solaris11 as zone of Omnios?

Comment: Sounds like blasphemy to me ;-).  I don't think the zones can natively be anything other than the parent OS.  lx zones can emulate a linux kernel (but are not that).  I would suggest asking the illumos mailing list but I suspect this question would not be well received :-P

Comment: I agree with you,but a Os with emulation of zones with other os,for example Solaris10 is not a bad idea

Comment: @elbarna But that's still the same kernel, designed to do just that.  You're asking if it's possible to run another kernel in a zone - and no, it's not.

Comment: Thanks,please add as answer, so I can vote and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one can install Solaris11 as OmniOS zone using the new [bhyve and KVM branded zones](https://omniosce.org/info/bhyve_kvm_brand.html) introduced a few weeks ago with OmniOS r151028.